# Saving images after altering them by CamanJS plugin

Tags: php, javascript, html, web

So I have some images and I could sucessfuly apply effects to them by using the CamanJS plugin. But now I want to save these altered images and replace them with the original one.

The documentation ([link](https://github.com/meltingice/CamanJS/wiki/How-to-use#saving-images)) Provides information on saving images. but it is seen as a download prompt. I want the images to be saved at the server without a prompt and on the click of the "save" button.

The documentation also says something about base64 encoding which I dont understand. Could my problem be solved?
thanks!.

Answer (score 17):

CamanJS has a built-in function that helps you get the Base64 representation of the image. You can send that to the server via Ajax, decode the base64 string, and save it as a normal image.

```
Caman("#my-image", function () {
  this.brightness(10);
  this.render(function () {
    var image = this.toBase64();
    saveToServer(image); // your ajax function
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

As you can see in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6150397/1437005 you can obtain the base64 representation of an image using `<canvas>` and the function `toDataURL()`.

When you get the base64 string you can use AJAX to send the image to the server (you can use jQuery `$.ajax` or `$.post` methods) and then in the server you can decode de base64 string to an image and stores it.

Answer (score 0):

Or Instead of sending the Base64 version to the server and doing the conversion, you can do the same on the front end itself and then upload the file to replace your image. That way you don't need to write a new service to convert and replace. Obtain the Base64 data as @Ryan mentioned and then use the below function to convert it to File/Blob.

```
export const convertToBlob = (data, successCallBack, errorCallback) => {
  fetch(data)
  .then((res) => res.blob())
  .then((blob) => successCallBack(blob))
  .catch((err) => errorCallback(err))
}

export const successCallBack = (blob) => { uploadBlobToServer(blob) }
```

If your service only accepts File object (not a Blob object) simply convert Blob to File using:

```
const imageFile = new File([blob], "imageFileName")
```